# invalid datatype error on foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving an error on the last line of the second query before the semi-colon saying operator_class is an invalid datatype for the foreign key, why am I receiving this error?

```
CREATE TABLE Qualification(
   operator_class VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,description VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle_Type(
   type   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,capacity NUMBER(3,0)
  ,fuel   VARCHAR2(10),
  operator_class VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
  constraint foreign key (operator_class) references Qualification(operator_class)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`varchar(2)` and `varchar2(2)` are not the same type.  Oracle recommends (still) `varchar2()`, so change the first table to:

```
CREATE TABLE Qualification (
   operator_class VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
-------------------------^
   description VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE Qualification(
   operator_class VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,description VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle_Type(
   type   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,capacity NUMBER(3,0)
  ,fuel   VARCHAR2(10),
  operator_class VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
  constraint constraint_name_FK foreign key (operator_class) references Qualification(operator_class)
);

adding a constraint name "constraint_name_FK" solved my error